# regular IVR uptime testing

Tags: asterisk, pbx

Greetings

I am looking for a services, that can test my IVR system for regular uptime testing, I am based in South Africa, so I would like a local service, but I do realise I might have to get a services from beyond the borders.

My IVR system is part of your Asterisk PBX, we have several phone number to be tested going to sveral different IVR menu systems within.

Thanks
Kowen

Answer (score 1):

[Empirix](http://www.empirix.com) is THE company for callcenter/IVR testing. They offer outsourced testing, as well as selling hardware so that you can test your own equipment. We use one of their boxes to test about 1500 IVR lines

It can recurse through all of your IVR menus, with speech req as well as other testing options.

Comment: I am looking for something like this, can you advised me if they only deal with large clients, and what is the cost options involved, I as failed to find that info on the website.

Comment: They will deal with anyone, although if you decide to go the route of of purchasing one to run on your own it is quite expensive. I can't speak to the outsourcing as we don't utilize that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably another Asterisk box to dial in and run tests?

You'd need to write code/scripts to conduct the tests though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am seeking a service, rather than building a system, due to service level agreements, I cant use our own stuff, as this was the orginal idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using another Asterisk box to do this is possible, though not terribly simple.

Assuming that you just want to check that the IVR answers and starts into the menu, you need a tone or sound file that can be programmatically analyzed.  You dial into the IVR using the other Asterisk box while recording the call, hang up after a few seconds, then perform analysis on the recorded file.  If you find the waveform you expect, the system is up.  If not, you can raise an alarm.

If you need to test deeper levels of the IVR, you can have multiple tones.

This may require some more advanced signal processing out there, but the techniques for doing such analysis is well documented.  Simpler analysis will do if you're just trying to determine if you've received your tone instead of a PSTN announcement.

The tone tends to be something customer friendly, as it will be heard by people calling in as well (unless you use a different route into the IVR and use conditionals in the dialplan to decide whether the tone is played).  Of course, at that point you're not really testing the IVR the customers use.

Comment: Like, I said earlier: Thank you for your answer, I am seeking a service, rather than building a system, due to service level agreements, I cant use our own stuff, as this was the orginal idea.